# sonarlint JavaScript warning: "Remove the unnecessary boolean literal"

Tags: javascript, sonarlint

Please note: as far as I'm aware this isn't a duplicate. There is some discussion about this warning in other languages but as we all know, `==` in JavaScript isn't like other languages.

The code reads:

```
let channelValue = filter == true ? 2 : 1;
```

SonarLint suggests "remove the unnecessary boolean literal, which tempts me to write:

```
let channelValue = filter ? 2 : 1;
```

but of course that will give a different result if filter has the value `87` or `"Cheese on Toast"`. Is there a way to avoid the `== true` ***but retain the same semantics?***

Comment: Maybe `!!filter`

Comment: Or maybe `filter === true` if it should yield `2` only when `filter` is an actual boolean `true`.

Comment: both `!!` and `==true` are changing the semantics. This is someone else's code which I'm maintaining and I don't want to risk changing what it does.

Comment: I don't think you can avoid the `== true` whilst retaining the semantics as you have already discovered.  Passing a non Boolean value in `filter` (0, null, undefined or NaN) will be falsey whilst (object, array, non empty string, any number > 0 or a Date) will be truthy. Therefore, 87 == true will be falsey whilst 87 will be truthy . Out of interest ESLint recommends changing `==` to `===` as suggested above. I would consider the sonarlint suggestion S1125 to be slightly dangerous in this example unless you can guarantee that the type of `filter` is a Boolean (typeof filter === 'Boolean').

Comment: If you're the maintainer of the code, please share with us the meaning of the code since we have no way of knowing how changing `==` to `===` would truly be a change in semantics. Show us how `filter == true` to `filter === true` or `filter` is significantly different. If you're able to change code, modify the changes to one of the solutions and test it before pushing the changes back to the live code.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using `===` instead of `==` as the second one is not recommended and may behave unexpectedly. It also resolves sonarlint warning.
So you code should look like this:

```js
let channelValue = filter === true ? 2 : 1;
```

Comment: Answer above is correct. When using the type safe comparison operators you are both checking that the values are equal (or unequal) and that their type is the same. Without the type safe comparison operators you are allowing the JavaScript engine the freedom to coerce your variables to true or false based on the truthy/falsey logic.

Comment: Thanks but I'm already aware of that. my question was how to rewrite the code to remove the warning *but retain the same semantics*

Comment: @RobinWebb Truthy and falsy apply when a value is encountered in a boolean context. That is different from comparing it using `==`. (As OP correctly mentioned `87 == true` is false while 87 is a truthy value.)